# Reference SlicerCache by name, not number

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code referencing Slicers:

```
For Each item In wb.SlicerCaches("Segment").SlicerItems
    If item.Selected = True Then
        If Len(sSegment) > 0 Then sSegment = sSegment & "|"
        sSegment = sSegment & item.Caption
    End If
Next item
```

but I get `Invalid procedure call or argument`.  I've seen many examples referencing them by name, but can't get it to work.  If I use (1), (3) etc and then add a slicer, it messes up the order, so the code is mucked up.

How can I reference them by name, my end goal is to iterate through selected items.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reference the slicercache by adding `Slicer_` in front of it.

For example, I added an `Authors` slicer to a table containing information about books and I could reference it by using this code:

```
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Author").Slicers("Author").Caption
```

The reason I knew to add `Slicer_` is because I right clicked the slicer and then selected `Slicer Settings...` and saw this:

[image: Slicer Info]

And that seems to reference the slicer fine.  It was really dumb luck that I happened to see that and thought to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
For Each item In wb.SlicerCaches.Item("Segment").SlicerItems
```